# Store the whole word using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

If String X contains String Y, then return the **entire word** that contains String Y. The idea is that RegEx needs to determine what is the entire word, I assume that regex will look for a whitespace.

```
String whole = "BARA BERE";
String part = "BAR";

if (whole.contains(part)) {
    result = whole.replaceAll("\\bBAR", "");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The output should be: *BARA*

**Q1:** What is the regex in this case?

**Q2:** What will be the regex, if the words are delimited by new lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match with this regex:

```
(?=\S*?BAR)\S+
```

This asserts that the non-whitespace sequence includes the word **"BAR"**.

```
String whole = "foo foobar barfoo baz";
String part = "foo";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?=\\S*?" + part + ")\\S+").matcher(whole);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

You get:

> foo
>   foobar
>   barfoo

You can also quote a literal section with `\Q\E` if your string contains meta-characters:

```
(?=\S*?\Q%s\E)\S+
```

```
String whole = "Dr Smith.";
String part = "th.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(String.format("(?=\\S*?\\Q%s\\E)\\S+", part)).matcher(whole);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: #Incompatible types: Pattern cannot be converted to Matcher

Comment: @insanovation I blame my kitten which entered a newline for me when I meant to complete the matcher declaration. Fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: I also need for an ignore case operation. For example: String part = "TH.".

Comment: You can compile the pattern with `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag. Change `Pattern.compile(...). ...` to `Pattern.compile(..., Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE). ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching for a word, you shouldn't be using [`.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) but `.find()`. Since you specified at least that's my interpretation) that a "word" should end at the nearest whitespace character, you can do this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\bBAR\\S*");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(whole);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    part = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

`\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace characters (which also excludes newlines).

If you want to allow spaces but forbid newlines within a "word", use `[^\r\n]` instead of `\S`.

Comment: Thank you, but what is you opinion on Q2: What will be the regex, if the words are delimited by new lines?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression must be

```
\bBAR\w*?\b
```

`\b` asserts a word boundary.

here assuming `part` string as `BAR`

.*? matches any number of characters in a lazy manner. That is until it finds the next word boundary `\b`